# How to run this package (RHex simulation with Gazebo)

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody!

I'm trying to simulate a RHex robot ([RHex](http://www.bostondynamics.com/robot_rhex.html))

[image description http://kodlab.seas.upenn.edu/uploads/RHex/rhex.jpg](http://kodlab.seas.upenn.edu/uploads/RHex/rhex.jpg)

I've found this package in github ([CE216](https://github.com/mugenZebra/CE216-project)) from mugenZebra but I don't know how to run it.

I just launched the world with: gazebo model_push.world

But I don't know how to run any script inside the folder, and I don't see any launch file…

Thanks a lot!

Jorge

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216405/how-to-run-this-package-(rhex-simulation-with-gazebo)/) by [silth](https://answers.ros.org/users/23638/silth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2015-08-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like this is not a ROS package, but intended for direct use with Gazebo. See the [Gazebo write_plugin](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=write_plugin) tutorial for an explanation of how that works.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [silth](https://answers.ros.org/users/23638/silth/) on 2015-08-24**:
Yes Stefan, you're right! (:

I'm going to try it